# Combining two task in gulp version 4

Tags: gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('minifyCSS', function() {
   gulp.src(['src/styles/*.css'])
   .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
   .pipe(autoprefix('last 2 versions'))
   .pipe(minifyCSS())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles/'));
});

gulp.task('compressJS', function() {
  gulp.src('src/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts/'))
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('compressJS','minifyCSS'));
```

We have defined two tasks in the gulpfile.js - compressJS and minifyCSS.
Below command gives the desired output:

```
gulp minifyCSS compressJS
```

But if we give the following command:

```
gulp default
```

We get an output of the first task passed in the series, that is only the compressJS is executed in this case

Could anyone help me to combine the above 2 tasks "minifyCSS and compressJS" when i run command "gulp default"

Comment: Add a return statement before `gulp.src` in both tasks.

Comment: thank you so much! adding return statement before gulp.src worked!